# Groovy coding conventions?

Tags: java, ruby, groovy

What is the standard coding convention for Groovy?

In Java the method naming is done using camel case notation.

```
public void calculateTotal() {}
```

In Ruby on which Groovy is based, underscores are preferred.

```
def calculate_total()
end
```

Which of the above two styles would be considered more Groovyist?

Personally I'm more inclined to use the Ruby style. Is there a standard document/general consensus among the Groovy community as to what is preferable?

Comment: BTW, the preferred Ruby style would be leaving out the parentheses for no-argument method definitions, i.e. `def calculate_total; end`, :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first one. Groovy took a lot from Ruby, but its main focus is to be a dynamic and powerful language that plays well with Java. Therefore, most Java coding conventions and coding styles apply to Groovy as well.

About naming conventions, while I also prefer the `underscore_separated_words` style of Ruby/Python and others, I think sticking to convention and being consistent with the surrounding environment is much more important than personal preference in these kind-of-superfluous matters (there are other things, like preferring a functional style over imperative constructs or vice versa, that I think are more interesting to discuss.

So, always use `camelCasing` for Groovy methods. The [Groovy documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) uses them; all the methods from the standard library use them.

Finally, here's a nice [Groovy coding conventions guide](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html). It doesn't do any mention about naming conventions or formatting, but it introduces many of Groovy's nice syntactic additions and explains when it's preferred to use them

Comment: There's no debate, and it's not superfluous, functional style is the way to go. :)

Comment: @KshitizSharma Sorry, i think i didn't phrase that very well. I meant to say that "camelCase vs underscore_separated" was a superfluous debate, but other things like "functional vs imperative style" (in languages that allow both quite directly) are much deeper and interesting to debate :)

Comment: Should camelCase also be used for variables?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yes. Only constants should be SNAKE_CASE.

Comment: is groovy.codehaus.org still up?

Comment: There is a list of IDEs that do auto-refactoring here: http://groovy-lang.org/ides.html. Might be of use.